# Android drag a view along side a path

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have path and I want to drag my view in that path vertically.
this is my `onTouchListener` code for the view:

```
val point = FloatArray(2)
val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(path, true)

 tooltipView.setOnTouchListener(object :View.OnTouchListener{
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                onDataPointTouchListener()
                if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    v?.performClick()
                    pathMeasure.getPosTan(event.x, point, null) // This is where I get path point
                    v?.x = point[0] - tooltipWith / 2
                    v?.y = point[1] - tooltipHeight
                }else if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    tooltipView.animate().translationX(previousX - tooltipWith / 2)
                    tooltipView.animate().translationY(previousY - tooltipHeight)
                    layoutDate.visible()
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```

Can someone please help me. My path is a curved line. I want to be able to drag the view in that line.Just like a seekbar:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is somewhat difficult and depends on what short cuts you are willing to make.

The simplest I can think of is:
Use pathMeasure to walk the path and decide which to which point on the path your finger is closest (loop across the entire path comparing with event.x/y ).  Move the position to that point. This is not as smooth as seekbar. Which animates to your finger.

Comment: Thank you. I fix the problem in some other ways. but your description is quite true.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to use MotionLayout (constraint layout 2 library) - you only need to set an XML file with 2 constraint sets and library handles the rest.

You can also add path coordinates at a specific progress and the library creates path interpulation.

References:

1. [Manage motion and widget animation with MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout)
2. [MotionLayout examples](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples)

Comment: Thanks. but I'm using custom layout. This is a chart that I want to user to be able to drag the tool tip with touch.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. Do you want the path animation to start once the user release the drag?

Comment: No. I updated the question. please take a look

Comment: Sounds like motion layout use case to me, unless you don't have a layout xml

Comment: Yes. I don't have a layout.xml.

Comment: I'm finally convinced :) and now curious to know if motion layout can be configured dynamically. after all, it's a constraint layout with muscles.

Comment: That is interesting. but in my case the line is dynamic and change it's shape base on input data.